# es6 export throws Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

## App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

     class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <p>
                Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
              </p>
              <a
                className="App-link"
                href="https://reactjs.org"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                Learn React
              </a>
            </header>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

    export App
```

## index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import   App   from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

(1)When I run the the above code I am getting the below error at last line of App.js i.e export statement

```
"parsing error:unexpected token"
```

The error wouldnt go away even when imported the module as

```
import   { App }  from './App';
```

I am aware that we can fix this error by writing

```
export default App
```

instead of

```
export App
```

it also works if we just append export to App as below

```
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I am not able to figure out this behavior of export statement  .I googled but they are only confusing me more.

2)Also whats the difference between

```
export App
```

vs

```
export const App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You get an error because you have invalid export syntax. Try `export class App` instead.
2. When you write `export class App`, it means that you export a class with a name 'App' from this module. It could be imported then by its name like so: `import { App } from App.js`;
3. `export default` makes passed entity a default exported entity. It means that when you don't specify a name in import statement, default entity will be imported.

```
// App.js
export default App;

// other_module.js
import App from App.js // import default from App.js and put it into 'App' var
```

4. `export const App` means that App won't change in the module from which it was imported. `export App` is invalid syntax, take a look at `export let` for clarification on what's the difference.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita shalin ."export default App " works without mentioning type as class.why i need to mention the type of App while exporting as "export class App"?we can export any object using export ,correct? like "export { login,logout } ".class which is a syntactic sugar for function is also an object ,so why cant i simply attach export  in front of any object to have it exported? I am only used to NodejS common js syntax.newbie to es6 moudles.

Comment: @venkata, "export default" accepts any kind of statement: variable, class declaration or function declaration. Other exports are called "named exports" and you should either prepend "export" to var, function or class declaration or export already declared entity like so: "export { App };"

Comment: @venkata, you are right. You can export an object directly or a constant by saying `export const foo = 'bar'`. But your syntax is invalid. While exporting you have to mention what type it is. If it is an object export { foo }, if constant export const and if class, export class. Else use default which will the value defined. You can get more information about exports here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export